# Need transparent borders on kendo popup modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement a transparent border around kendogrid popup. I have managed to apply around the kendogrid by enclosing  the grid in div and applying the following style to the div.

```
border: 20px solid rgb(100, 100, 100); /* default color */
border: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* rgba for transparency */
```

I am not sure how to enclose a popup withing a div and apply the style accordingly. Could somebody help me please

**html**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.TeamViewModel>()
    .Name("GridTeam")
    //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 700px"})
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamName);
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamDescription);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CountryCode);

    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Team"))
     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
     .TemplateName("TeamEdit")
        .Window(w => w.Width(500))
     )
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new string[] { "15", "30", "45", "60" }))
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("userProfileTemplate")
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("onRowBound")
    .DetailExpand("expandRow"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(t => t.TeamID))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Team_Create", "Admin"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Team_Read", "Admin"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Team_Update", "Admin"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Team_Delete", "Admin"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.Edit("insertPopupCaption"))
    )
```

**UI**

[image]

**Rendered html**

[image]

Comment: As I said at your previous post, we need rendered HTML and CSS, and not as image, as code .... reproducing the issue you need help with

Comment: I have actually pasted  the screenshot of the rendered html using developer tools above.Do you mean you need the full page source

Comment: If you don't know what I mean, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have provided the html. There is no css currently applied to the popup dialog. I know what css to apply but dont know how to apply it and thats what my question is. I am not sure how to recreate my solution as it is using kendo control. The link that you shared just tells about recreating the problem.  It would have been easier using standing mvc controls. I am not sure how to recreate the problem with kendo